# Javascript Placeholder (input) display ampersand text correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var inputSearchField = document.createElement('input');
inputSearchField.id = 'searchField';
inputSearchField.type = 'text';
inputSearchField.placeholder = "Rechercher un &eacute;quipier";
searchDiv.appendChild(inputSearchField);
```

The result of the above shows in the browser (as the Placeholder text): **Rechercher un &eacute;quipier**

I was expecting the result to be: **Rechercher un équipier**.

Is there any way to achieve the above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly use the respective [Unicode identifier](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm), if your document is coded in UTF8:

```
inputSearchField.placeholder = "Rechercher un \u00E9quipier";
```

Comment: Or just use the `é` character directly! Javascript is happy with Unicode characters!